# How to add images from database with caption

Tags: php, html, css

What I want to do is that, It should display 3 images on every line and along with their captions.And their could be many rows. How can do that ? here is my code..

```
while($info=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $image=$info['image'];
    $cap=$info['caption'];
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" />';
    echo $cap;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the HTML that will be output?

Comment: Sounds like you might need to use a table. Aggregate every n results (where n is the number of columns you want) and output two rows every time you have n pieces of data. One row for the images, one row for the caption.

Comment: You may want to try referencing the image location by URL along with the captions

Comment: @Greg and Can you please elaborate it or please provide me code ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.
I don't know hows its working . But it is ....

```
<table>

            <?php
            $i=1;
         $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM publish");

        while($info=mysql_fetch_array($query))
         {
        $inq=$info['ref'];
        $imagesrc=$info['image'];
        $ti=$info['title'];
        if($i%3==1 || $info['id']==1 )
        {
        echo "<tr></tr>";

        }
        ?>
        <td>
            <a href="movieview.php?ref=<?php echo $info['ref']; ?>">
            <?php

            echo    '<img src="admin/'.$imagesrc.'" style="width:138px;height:200px;" />';

                echo '</a><br />';
                echo $ti;

            $i++;
        }
    ?>
    </td>

    </table>
```